# How to get calendar event updates on Android device?

Tags: android, calendar

I want to get calendar event updates (when a new event is added or an existing event is deleted ) on android 2.2 devices ?

In other words, my program wants to get notifications for any calendar event changes

Anyone has any thoughts regarding how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

whenever the Calendar update is made,u can get notification by using Content Observer,u have to register first observer using

this.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, true, observer);

where uri is the the calendar uri like "content://com.android.calendar/events" and observer is the object of the class extending Content Observer which overrides on change method,invoked when the change occurs

you have to notify this observer using
this.getContentResolver().notifyChange(eventsUri, null)
wherever u r performing changes like in read or delete operation of the calendar